# Raspbian reboot failure - wpa_supplicant but there is an ethernet connection

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm using Raspberry Pi 2 with RASPBIAN (Debian Wheezy) ~ Release date:2015-05-05.

I've just rebuilt it for the second time, including reprogramming the SD card. Both times, intial boot takes me into raspi-config and I am able to get up and running with the GUI, accessing the network and internet without problems. When I went to reboot, I get the message :

```
   wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start  
   run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1  
   if-up.d/mountnfs[wlan0]:waiting for interface wlan1 before doing NFS mounts
```

And it just sits there.

I have a working ethernet connection and **no** WLAN connection.

Questions :

1. Did I miss something in the initial setup? I didn't do anything with the network connections
2. Is there some way to recover without rebuilding? I can move the SD card to a windows machine, if that helps.

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`? If you post it here, don't forget to blank out SSID and pre-shared key.  What does `/var/log/syslog` show?

Comment: The first 2 errors are normal. The new `Raspbian` uses `dhcpd` and does not require the `wpa_supplicant daemon` (it uses `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant`). Waiting for `nfs` should not halt boot. Do you get a prompt or is the system unresponsive.

Comment: I can't look at /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf because the system isn't running. I can reburn the SD card and start over, but I didn't want to do this (as this is already the second time around) until I had exhausted any other suggestions from this forum. 

Is there something I should be looking for in wpa_supplicant.conf? I have not done anything that would change it, to my knowledge.

Suggestions?